# DropDown Selected Value not Showing up

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have drop-down inside of a gridview so when the gridview is loaded and the drop-down is bound then the drop-down only show the first value of the drop-down list and it is not showing the previously selected value.  When the gridview loads, i would like the drop-down to show what was previously selected for that row.  Here is my code:
aspx markup for the drop-down:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Answer">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lblAns" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("DDL_ANS")%>' Visible="false"></asp:Label>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl_Answer" runat="server">
        </asp:DropDownList>
    </ItemTemplate>
```

Here is code behind:

```
protected void RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        DropDownList ddl_Answer;
        //get current index selected
        int current_quest = Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.DataKeys[e.Row.RowIndex].Value);
        ddl_Answer = e.Row.FindControl("ddl_Answer") as DropDownList;
        using (SqlConnection con2 = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myconnection"].ConnectionString))
        {
            con2.Open();
            using (SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("select distinct DD_ANSWER from table1 where ID= '" + current_quest + "' ", con2))
            {
                ddl_Answer.DataSource = cmd1.ExecuteReader();
                ddl_Answer.DataTextField = "DD_ANSWER";
                ddl_Answer.DataValueField = "DD_ANSWER";
                ddl_Answer.DataBind();                        
            }
                con2.Close();
        }

    }
```

I have tried to add this line of code after binding but i get this error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

```
ddl_Answer.Items.FindByValue((e.Row.FindControl("lblAns") as Label).Text).Selected = true;
```

thanks

Comment: Your missing a bracket for the end of your if statement I think?

Comment: thanks but that is the issue, i just forgot to add the bracket when i was pasting the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe in your `SELECT` you need to use `current_quest_sk` instead of `current_quest`

Aslo try to check for null before accessing your controls:

```
var ddl_Answer = e.Row.FindControl("ddl_Answer") as DropDownList;
var answerLabel = e.Row.FindControl("lblAns") as Label;
if(answerLabel !=null && ddl_Answer!=null)
{
    ddl_Answer.Items.FindByValue(answerLabel.Text).Selected = true;
}
```

---

`@afzalulh` has a valid point remove quotes if `current_quest_sk`(ID) is an Integer in your table.

You should avoid SQL injection but that's a different topic.

Comment: +1 - I was just typing this answer! Also, the ID is probably integer, so OP should remove the `'` in select statement.

Answer (score 0):

Place a breakpoint in your code, and setup through it with your debugger.

Either you have a typo in one of your string names or you are looking at the wrong control.

Stepping through your code will help you see exactly what line of your code is causing the problem.

You could also put a try/catch block around the whole thing to help you isolate the problem. Once you find the problem, remove the try/catch block.